# WooCommerce woocommerce_product_query get IDS

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to get the IDS of WooCommerce main query inside the hook 'woocommerce_product_query'

I tried to do something like this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_get_IDS' );
function custom_get_IDS( $q ) {
    if($q->have_posts()){
        while($q->have_posts()){
            $q->the_post();
            //get the id
            echo 'print the ID';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'no posts';
    }
}
```

but this print always "no posts" even though the page loop have 2 products.

If i do

```
print_r($q);
```

i get the WP_Query Object with all query settings like

```
[query] => Array
    (
        [s] => my_query_word
        [post_type] => product
        [lang] => en
    )

[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [s] => my_query_word
        [post_type] => product
        [lang] => en
        [error] => 
        [m] => 
        [p] => 0
        [post_parent] => 
etc etc etc
```

How can I get the IDS of $q Query inside the woocommerce_product_query hook?

I have to do this inside the woocommerce_product_query hook.

Comment: the hook `woocommerce_product_query` is made to manipulate existing WooCommerce product queries, but not to set a query loop inside it… see [some StackOverFlow existing examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=woocommerce_product_query) with this hook…

Comment: The problem with the action 'woocommerce_product_query' is that it is called from the WordPress action 'pre_get_posts' which means at this point in time the query has not yet been done which means $q has no posts.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended but this may get you the desired output.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_get_IDS' );

function custom_get_IDS( $q ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_get_IDS' );

    $posts = $q->get_posts();
    if ( $posts ) {
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            //get the id
            echo 'print the ID=' . $post->ID;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'no posts';
    }
}
```